# "Уииииии" appears frequently in social media. What does it mean?

Tags: перевод

What does "уииииии" mean?  Is it an extended acronym?

For example here (http://risovach.ru/upload/2014/08/mem/filosoraptor_58953516_orig_.jpg):

[image]

or here (http://demotivatori.net/sozdanije/posters2/b04a316a10e7e609a6d0c7de158451be.png):

[image]

Comment: This is the most hillarious question in Russian SE section!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"уииииии" it's just the sound that you issue being crowded emotions when sliding down the snow slides or water slides, or something like that. Or when you get for something big, long expected, an awesome thing or event.

Comment: The simplicity and truth of this answer tempts me to select it as the answer. It describes what it is and when/why it is used.

Comment: A native speaker also liked this description, adding "... or when you get a long expected drink )"

Answer (score 12):

Would this not simply be a calque of the English word "whee!" ?

Comment: I'm no linguist and had never heard of a "calque" before, though I have noticed examples of them. Perhaps listening to a calque is all that is required to understand it.

Comment: @rickhg12hs: that's not a calque, that's a loanword. A loanword is borrowed from another language as is: *офис* < "office", *кроль* < "crawl" etc. A calque is a root-for-root translation: *небоскрёб* < "skyscraper", *тяни-толкай* < "push-pull" etc.

Comment: @Quassnoi So, might this be a [Phono-semantic matching (PSM)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phono-semantic_matching)?

Comment: @rickhg12hs: it's an onomatopoeia (*звукоподражание*), its meaning is defined by its sound, it has no meaning distinct from its sound. An example of PSM in Russian would be *рында* ("ship's bell") < *рынду бей* < "ring the bell", the word *рында* having been extant with another meaning in Russian by the time *рынду бей* had been borrowed.

Comment: @Quassnoi Again, I'm no expert, but aren't onomatopoeias referring to something concrete and specific, like "meow", etc. Did Russians borrow this from English, or did Russians create "уииииии" independently?

Comment: @rickhg12hs: honestly I don't know. My point is that *if* Russian borrowed it from English, it would be a loanword, not a calque.

Comment: @Quassnoi How about posting an answer and then we can read the feedback?

Comment: @rickhg12hs: answer given by Eugene is good enough, my answer would have been just the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32345/discussion-between-quassnoi-and-rickhg12hs).

Answer (score 1):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ds31EJ2cXPQ - "уииииии" is sound effect like in this video

Answer (score 0):

The same as Whee! in English.

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/whee
http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=whee

Means nothing in Russian.

Comment: If it means nothing in Russian, would it be accurate to say that they are speaking English for this word?

Comment: Yes. This is just a ways to transcribe English expression with Russian letters.

Comment: Is that a "calque"?

Comment: I guess so, yes.